# Manga about protagonist (male, high schooler) who died in road accident and wandering as ghost at his school

Tags: story-identification, manga, ghost

I need identification for manga with following description.

This is relatively recent manga with common (modern) art-style.

Protagonist always wear a tracksuit.

The protagonist (male) in the story has a childhood friend (female) and they go to same school. On the way (or near) to their school, there is a haunted road crossing. A long time ago, someone was died there (at least one girl). Soon protagonist also dies at the same crossing and becomes a ghost. At first, the protagonist seems not to believe that he already died. He still goes to school and sits at his own desk. But eventually he realizes that he is already dead, but he is still wandering at his school anyway.

Then, there is this girl at his school who can see him, but at first she just ignores him. But eventually she is willing to communicate with him.

This girl can only see him, but cannot hear him. Furthermore, from the girl's point of view, she can only clearly see the lower torso of the protagonist. The protagonist's face always seem covered by shadow. So, when the girl asks, protagonist can only answer "yes" by stomping his feet twice or "no" by stomping his feet once.

Later it shows that,back in the protagonist's childhood, he had a friend (girl) that also died at the same cross road.

Comment: If the answer posted is the correct one, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

#### おくることば ([*Okuru Kotoba*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/105875/Okuru_Kotoba), Words to Give) by Toshiko Machida

[image]

<sup>Cover of the 1st volume</sup>

#### Synopsis

> They say that a spirit sometimes appears on a certain crossing in town. One day, a high school boy named Sahara gets into an accident on that very crossing, causing him and his friends' lives to change forever.

---

The description in the question basically describes the content of the 1st volume.

> Protagonist always wear a tracksuit.

[image]

> At first, the protagonist seems not to believe that he already died. He still goes to school and sits at his own desk. But eventually he realizes that he is already dead, but he is still wandering at his school anyway.

[image]

> This girl can only see him, but cannot hear him. Furthermore, from the girl's point of view, she can only clearly see the lower torso of the protagonist. The protagonist's face always seem covered by shadow. So, when the girl asks, protagonist can only answer "yes" by stomping his feet twice or "no" by stomping his feet once.

[image]

Comment: Nice! How did you find it?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I own the digital Japanese version, so it's not that useful :/

Comment: Ah, prior experience. That's what a lot of us use around here. Still, thank you for sharing.